# The Abhidamma Pitaka

Tags: reference-request, abhidhamma, tipitaka

Can anyone help me with finding *The Abhidamma Pitaka* or some of the 7 books from it?

I seem not to be able to find anything when searching on google. Maybe im just not skilled enough to find books/pdf's about it. I can find only descriptions of what The Abhidhamma Pitaka is and what it contains.

I would like to find it in english since i cannot read other languages.

I really want to begin studying this Pitaka. Help would be much appreciated.

May all beings be happy, peaceful and free from mental and physical suffering.

Harshani

--Update--

I just found this: http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/abhidhaultsci.pdf
I think its a condensation of the most essential teachings from The Abhidhamma Pitaka. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for a nearly identical post to another question, but:

You can get a hard copy text of the Pali Text Society edition from:

The Pali Text Society: http://palitext.com
(they also have sets of the translations) Become a member and receive a nice discount.

You can find an on-line version of the BJT text at:
Metta Net Lanka:
http://www.metta.lk/tipitaka/index.html

You can get a searchable CD from the Vipassana Research Institute:
http://www.vridhamma.org/Chattha-Sangayana-CD-ROM-Update

These have the Abhidhamma texts.

EDIT: In response to your revised question. I have the Abhidhamma texts. The books are:
Abhidhamma Pitaka

Dhammasangani: Buddhist Psychological Ethics
Vibhanga: The Book of Analysis
Dhatukath¤: Discourse on Elements
Puggalapannatti: A Designation of Human Types
Kathavatthu: Points of Controversy
Yamaka: — 
Tikapatthana: Conditional Relations
Dukapatthana: —

I believe the book you have linked to is a new work constructed along the lines of the Abhidhamma. There may be others that can inform you better about that.

Comment: Wow thank you so much Obo :) Have you gotten a hardcopy? I mean if its an entire pitaka that must be thousands of pages, right? I forgot to say that i can only read english. Can you read my question again - i just found a link to a PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Also check out suttacentral.net, Abhidhamma section and Ven. Bodhi's great lecture series [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSL1N5caXZM)

Comment: Hi Santa and thank you so much for your help:) I really appreciate all the help i get.

Comment: I have now watched the first video (1/15) of the Adhidhamma retreat by Ven. Bodhi. Im in middle of the second one. Im amazed of how much he knows its really a joy to watch and learn from him. I feel so lucky to have the oppertunity to listen to this teaching. Again thank you Santa for showing me this buddhist monk. Wish you well:)

Comment: He definitely knows his stuff...:oD

Comment: Yes he does. Im at the 4/15 now and i have his book on Abhidhamma Sangaha also. The abhidhamma is very deep and complex so im happy i have Bhikkhu Bodhi as a teacher:) You can get his book here: http://store.pariyatti.org/Comprehensive-Manual-of-Abhidhamma-A--PDF-eBook_p_4362.html

Comment: I just found 79 dhamma talks by Bhikkhu Bodhi. http://bodhimonastery.org/a-systematic-study-of-the-majjhima-nikaya.html